# Google Visualization Column and Bar chart vaxis and haxis labels overlap in firefox 3.6.12 and IE

Tags: google-visualization

Can anyone help me on this problem I am having with chart labels on 
firefox and IE8, on chrome and safari the labels are working as they 
are expected to, but on Firefox and IE, the axis labels will overlap 
each other and won't obey any of the haxis or vaxis options.  I am coding 
in ruby on rails and using an erb template partial to write out my 
javascript.  As I said before, it works great on chrome and safari but 
on firefox and IE8 I run into these axis label problems.  Any help 
would be grateful.

This is the code I am doing

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBarChart);

function drawBarChart() {
  var bar_data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  bar_data.addColumn('string', 'yaxis');
  bar_data.addColumn('number', 'xaxis');
  bar_data.addRows(5);
  var col = 0;
  <% array.each do |value| %>
    bar_data.setValue(col, 0, 'realllly longggggggggggggggggggggggggg');
    bar_data.setValue(col, 1, <%= value %>);
    col++;
  <% end %>

var bar_chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('<%= element %>'));
bar_chart.draw(
  bar_data,
  {
    width: 870,
    height: 350,
    title: 'Quantity per Suspect Code',
    legend: 'none',
    vAxis: {
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 11
      }
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Quantity'
    }
  }
) };

  </script>
```

Notes: The element id is passed to this partial, so in this case the element would be 'line_chart' and the id on the template rendering this partial is #line_chart

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same problem with an area chart. Just started to dive into this. Will let you know when I find something. I started to play around with the [chart doc](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart.html#Configuration_Options)